# Large test virus file for ClamAV

Tags: anti-virus, clamav

I need a test file larger than 10K that will trigger ClamAV

As per [Large Virus File with EICAR-Test-Signature not identified by the clamav library](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003097/large-virus-file-with-eicar-test-signature-not-identified-by-the-clamav-library) , ClamAV will not detect the EICAR test virus when it is embedded inside a larger file (even though many other AVs will).

Does anyone know what my options are here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that a zip file containing the EICAR test virus plus other files does get flagged by ClamAV and can be made as large or small as necessary.